# can't find gridView of binding object

Tags: android, gridview, binding

Codes as following

```java
public class GridMain extends AppCompatActivity {

private  ActivityMainBinding binding ; 
    .....
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater()) ; //  to get layout inflate
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_main);

        setContentView(binding.getRoot());  // To set contentView to the root

        String[] item_names = {   // the items' name from 1st to 10th
                                  "Import/Export",
                                  "Inventory",
                                  "Query" ,
                                  "Param",
                                  "Creation",
                                  "Setting",
                                  "Sync",
                                  "Modification",
                                  "Web",
                                  "Nothing"} ;

        int [] image_items = {  // the image of items from 1st to 10th
                R.drawable.image_1,
                R.drawable.image_2,
                R.drawable.image_3,
                R.drawable.image_4,
                R.drawable.image_5,
                R.drawable.image_6,
                R.drawable.image_7,
                R.drawable.image_8,
                R.drawable.image_9,
                R.drawable.image_10
        } ;     // images of items

        GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(GridMain.this ,
                                                         item_names    ,
                                                         image_items   );    
binding.gridView
        ^^^^^^^^
```

my studio can't display "griview".

[image: Error showing image]

Because I want to use setAdapter() to set griewadapter.
can someone help me to resolve this problem ? Many thanks

I try to add some codes in my build.grade as follows :

```groovy
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

Comment: is `viewBinding = true` defined in *build.gradle(Module:app)* file? Consider adding the `ActivityMainBinding`'s xml implementation. This can be a definition or id error. Also you'd better edit that image and crop the unnecessary blank zones because it is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the content view twice. The first `setContentView` is not using your binding and that's why you can't use it (don't see changes) afterwards (the first view inflated is what is drawn in the screen).

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater()) ; // to get layout inflate 
// setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_main); <- THIS ONE IS NOT NEEDED
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

Also, consider adding the xml implementation to see if the name is not correct.